# Optimal way to render multiple scenes with large numbers of objects in Three.js

Tags: webgl, three.js

Imagine that you want to draw two scenes, each with hundreds of spheres, and provide the ability to switch between these scenes.  What is an optimal way to do this?

Currently a switch takes about 4 to 5 seconds because I am deleting, creating, and drawing all of the spheres on each switch.  Below is an example of the code that runs on a scene switch.

```
clearObjects();
resetCamera();  

for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 50, 50);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFFCC33});
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    sphere.position.set(randX, randY, randZ);

    scene.add(sphere);
    objects.push(sphere);   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once again, why don't you just use one scene, split it in 2 parts, set your camera FOV (field of view) so that you can see just one scene part at a time and then just move your camera position... Doesn't it sound more efficient?

If there are no particular reasons for using 2 scenes, you can always implement your code with just one scene. So try the method I described above or explain your reasons to use 2 scenes.

**Edit:** You can also use two `THREE.Object3D` containers to represent your 2 scenes, where you can store all of your certain scene objects and then just show/hide one of the containers at a time. Than way you can manipulate all of the container's contents using `yourContainer.children[n]`.

So generally, that is what you want to do:

```
var scene1Container = new THREE.Object3D();
var scene2Container = new THREE.Object3D();

scene1Container.add(firstObjectFromScene1);
//.....
scene1Container.add(nObjectFromScene1);

scene2Container.add(firstObjectFromScene2);
//.....
scene2Container.add(nObjectFromScene2);
```

now you can just show/hide one of the containers at a time using `scene1Container.visible = true/false;` (And manage `scene1Container.traverse` to apply visibility change to all of the children of your object).

Comment: I have controls set up that allow the user to move around the scene.

Comment: Then why don't you create an empty `var object = THREE.Object3D` container, add to it all of your scene#1 objects and add to scene only your container object. Then create another container and put there objects of scene#2. That way you could simply set `object.visible = true/false`

Comment: Nice.  I definitely see how setting the `object.visible` attribute would be a lot better than recreating and destroying all of the objects.  I had read a bit about making one master object containing multiple objects to increase efficiency.  One requirement of my project is to be able to click and focus on every sphere and I am not sure if I would be able to do that if I used that approach.

Comment: You certainly would be able to do that! Just reach your spheres like this: `containerObject.children[27]`. It' not like a `merge` method, where all of your objects meshes connect to each other, it's really like a container where you store your objects (like a folder on you PC).

Comment: Excellent!  Adding the objects to one `Object3D` before rendering and using the visibility tip to avoid destroying and recreating objects definitely increased efficiency.  Keep in mind that you will have to use `object.traverse` to hide the children since hiding the container does not cascade to the children.  See [this GitHub ticket](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1524).  Edit your answer to include the information we have discussed in comments and I will accept.

Comment: FYI since r71 three.js visibility affects children so no need for traversing

Comment: @Deminetix That's a great news!