# How do I load a new scene but be able to go back to the last? Like in a website

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is scene [one](http://goo.gl/2KqZG1) of many. 
I'd like to now load up scene 2 (another html file) and I'm not sure how the standard way of doing this is. The *fade to black* and *load new file* thing I have going on is boring. Ideally, I'd like to know how to implement a system where the user can see the next scene through the door. Then there would be a door to scene 3 further on, and so on.

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792083/optimal-way-to-render-multiple-scenes-with-large-numbers-of-objects-in-three-js), but it doesn't use flat html files and a url.

Also, what is up with that reflection mismatch in the water I have there?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new scene and render the scene the user is in. like so:

```
//create both scenes.
var activeScene = 0;
var scenes = [
    new THREE.Scene(),
    new THREE.Scene()
];


//inside the render function, check what scene the player is in
var render = function(){
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
        renderer.render( scenes[activeScene], camera );
};
```

all that remains is switching scenes by modifying the `activeScene` variable